# How to inject custom values for HMR variables for Vite app

Tags: vite, hmr

For example I want to redefine `__HMR_PORT__` value.

[image]

How to do it exactly? I tried several approaches with `.env` files in root folder of app, but this variable is `null` each time in DevTools.

Answer (score 0):

I've found solution by my own, it's quite simple. In `vite.config.js`:

```
export default defineConfig({
  server: {
    hmr: {
      clientPort: 800,
    }
  },
  plugins: [svelte()],
})
```